# How to process insert requests in Spring Data before adding them to MongoDB?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

after following the very useful tutorial at https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/ , I'm trying to create a link shortener app. I've coded an URL class (with `id`, `longURL` and `hash` attributes) and URLRepository class (for now, with just the `findByHash` method as shown in the demo). Please note that by "hash" I'm referring to a random short string generated by a method yet-to-be-implemented, not an actual hashing function like MD5. Just calls to a independent `generateHash(String URL)` for example

I'm able to add new entries into the database by using the REST interface provided by Spring, as well as fetching them. However I'd like to have the application generate the hash itself and making some checks and processing before storing it - Mainly checking that the URL is not already stored, in which case it will just return the existing hash.

I suppose that I'd have to extend `SimpleMongoRepository`'s  `<S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entites);` method (As extended by `MongoRepository`) under my `URLRepository` class, but I'm not really sure how to do that. I also saw the `insert` method and I don't know which one I should be using

URL.java

```
public class URL {

    @Id private String id;

    private String longURL;
    private String hash;

    public String getLongURL() {
        return longURL;
    }

    public void setLongURL(String longURL) {
        this.longURL = longURL;
    }

    public String getHash() {
        return hash;
    }

    public void setHash(String Hash) {
        this.hash = Hash;
    }

}
```

URLRepository.java

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "urls", path = "urls")
public interface URLRepository extends MongoRepository<URL, String> {

    List<URL> findByHash(@Param("hash") String hash);

}
```

Comment: No, extending `SimpleMongoRepository` is usually not the way to go. Would you mind adding some sample (pseudo) on what you're trying to achieve? It's a bit hard to digest from the prose. Also what does "have the application generate the hash itself" mean exactly? How is it currently obtaining the hash?

Comment: I'll ad my code right away, sorry! Currently I'm able to send a POST request containing the desired long URL and its hash. However what I want is to send just the long URL and let the application generate the hash by any means (Doesn't have to be an actual hash, it can be a random string or whatever, the implementation is not yet done and is open to changes in the future)

Comment: A cool feature would be to allow two types of link submitting: Either (a) a long URL and let the application generate and return its hash, or (b) sending both long URL and suggested hash, letting the app return the hash itself, or else an error message if the hash already exists/not valid/some other problem happened.But I'd be happy just to have the option (a) at least for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It feels like you're better off writing a custom controller instead of using Spring Data REST here as you basically need two resources: one to add a link or return an existing and a second one to retrieve an original URI via its hash.

In the first method you'd simply call a repository method `findByLongURL(…)` and use the obtained `URL` instance if you have a result or take a second step to actually create the hash and save the `URL` instance thought repository. The second resource would basically just call you already existing method.

That's straight forward and easy to digest.

If you need the implementation of the former method be an atomic operation the repository query method needs to be manually implemented (for general instructions on that read up the relevant section in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour)):

```
class UrlRepositoryImpl implements UrlRepositoryCustom {

  private final MongoOperations operations;

  public UrlRepositoryImpl(MongoOperations operations) {
    this.operations = operations;
  }

  @Override
  public URL findOrInsert(String source) {

    // What to find?
    Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("longURL").is(source);

    // What to write if nothing can be found
    Update update = new Update()
      .setOnInsert("longURL", source)
      .setOnInsert("hash", calculatedHash);

    FindAndModifyOptions options = new FindAndModifyOptions.options()
      .returnNew(true) // returns the document insert (if so)
      .upsert(true); // insert document if it doesn't exist

    return operations.findAndModify(query, update, options, URL.class);
  }
}
```

As you can see this involves dealing with some lower level details (although the verbosity can be reduced by using static imports) but basically gives you an atomic operation.

Comment: For the sake of helping novices like me, I found [here](http://ryanjbaxter.com/2014/12/17/building-rest-apis-with-spring-boot/) some useful examples to see the structure of the controller I had to code.

Comment: I did implement a custom Controller under UrlController class, and mapped my controller to handle requests on /api/urls, which it does fine. However I can still POST requests to /urls with no validation of any kind. How can I avoid this behaviour? And I can't map some static page to /urls because that's where my redirection system is going to operate, translating /xyzabc to the correct URL

Comment: This is what the app logs: DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/urls] -- Looking up handler method for path /urls -- Did not find handler method for [/urls] -- Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request -- Successfully completed request