# Override default dispatcherServlet when a custom REST controller has been created

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

Following [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827532/how-to-process-insert-requests-in-spring-data-before-adding-them-to-mongodb), I have succeded in creating a custom REST controller to handle different kinds of requests to */api/urls* and operate accordingly.

However, there is still a default controller handling requests at */urls* which affects my application: When receiving a request that is not */api/something*, it should fetch my database for the URL linked to said */whatever* and redirect the user there. Moreover, under */api/urls* I've developed certain validation rules to ensure integrity and optimization of the requests, which does not jhappen in /urls so anyone could insert any kind of data into my database.

What would be a possible way to disable this default handler? Seeing the logs I headed to register my own ServletRegistrationBean as instructed [here](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/011-add-servlet-mapping-to-dispatcherservlet-spring-boot/) but this is for having two isolated environments as far as I understand

My goal is to simply "disconnect" /urls URL from the default REST controller -which is no longer of any use to me now that I have my own one- and just use the custom one that I implemented in */api/urls* (Or whatever other URL I may decide to use such as "/service/shortener* if possible)

Below are my Java classes:

Url.java (getters and setters omitted for brevity):

```
@Document
public class Url {
    @Id private String id;
    private String longURL;
    private String hash;
    private String originalUrl;
    private String shortUri;
    private Date creationDate;
}
```

UrlRepository.java

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface UrlRepository extends MongoRepository<Url, String> {
    // Empty
}
```

UrlController.java:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/urls")
public class UrlController { 

    @Autowired
    private UrlRepository repo;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Url> getAll() {
        System.out.println("Showing all stored links");
        List<Url> results = repo.findAll();
        return results;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="{id}")
    public Url getUrl(@PathVariable String id) {
        System.out.println("Looking for URL " + id);
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public Url create(@RequestBody Url url) {
        System.out.println("Received POST " + url);
        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE, value="{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable String id) {
        //TBD
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="{id}")
    public Url update(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Url url) {
        //TBD
    }

}
```

Application.java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to hack your way around Spring Boot and Spring Data REST I strongly suggest to work WITH the frameworks instead of around them.

To change the default context-path from `/` to `/api` simply add a property to your `application.properties` file.

```
server.context-path=/api
```

Now you would need to change your controller mapping to `/urls` instead of `/api/urls`.

If you only want `/api` for Spring Data REST endpoints use the following property

```
spring.data.rest.base-uri=/api
```

This will make all Spring Data REST endpoints available under `/api`. You want to override the `/urls` so instead of using `@Controller` use `@RepositoryRestController` this will make your controller override the one registered by default.

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/urls")
public class UrlController { ... }
```

Comment: I may not have explained myself clear. I'd like to handle any request for _/*_ , while hosting internal app pages and its microservice endpoint under /api/ (For example, /api/home.html and /api/urls for the REST interface). However, I also want to redirect requests for URLs such as _/eU56x_ towards its corresponding link as stored in the DB. So, I'd like to handle any request from /* and then analyse it to route the user response accordingly. It's just that the default REST controller pins my database at /urls when it shouldn't be

Comment: Then, as mentioned in my answer, simply map the spring data rest stuff to `/api` and simply override the default controller (as explained in my answer). Then you can create an additional controller (or whatever) for the catch all and redirect to the correct URL.